# Wrong microcontroller found on Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino-leonardo

When I try to upload a sketch on this brand new Arduino Leonardo, I get this error:

```
Arduino: 1.6.11 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"

Sketch uses 4,134 bytes (14%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28,672 bytes.
Global variables use 148 bytes (5%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,412 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,560 bytes.


avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega32U4 is 1E 95 87
     Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.
Wrong microcontroller found.  Did you select the right board from the Tools > Board menu?
```

The output of "Get board info" is

```
BN: Arduino Leonardo
VID: 2A03
PID: 0036
SN: (null)
```

This is the actual board

[image]

And if I shine a very bright light on che microcontroller, take out my glasses and look veeeeeeery close at it, I can read MEGA32U4. So I think that this is an actual Arduino Leonardo.

I downloaded arduino.org IDE. After compiling ncurses5 (...) and making it starts, now i get this error

```
Arduino: 1.7.10 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"

/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/sketch_sep16a.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/sketch_sep16a.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/wiring.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/wiring_digital.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/wiring_analog.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/wiring_shift.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/hooks.c -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/hooks.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WInterrupts.c -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/WInterrupts.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -c -g -Os -w -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_pulse.c -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/wiring_pulse.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial1.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial0.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/USBCore.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/USBCore.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial2.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/main.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/main.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/abi.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/abi.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HardwareSerial.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial3.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/WString.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Stream.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/Stream.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Print.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/Print.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/CDC.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/CDC.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Tone.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/Tone.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HID.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HID.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WMath.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/WMath.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/IPAddress.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/IPAddress.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega32u4 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_LEONARDO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -DUSB_VID=0x2a03 -DUSB_PID=0x8036 -DUSB_MANUFACTURER="Unknown" -DUSB_PRODUCT="Arduino Leonardo" -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino -I/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/leonardo /home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/new.cpp -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/new.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/wiring.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/wiring_digital.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/wiring_analog.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/wiring_shift.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/hooks.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/WInterrupts.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/wiring_pulse.c.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/USBCore.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/main.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/abi.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HardwareSerial.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/WString.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/Stream.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/Print.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/CDC.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/Tone.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/HID.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/WMath.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/IPAddress.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-ar rcs /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/new.cpp.o 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc -w -Os -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega32u4 -o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/sketch_sep16a.cpp.elf /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/sketch_sep16a.cpp.o /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/core.a -L/tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp -lm 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/sketch_sep16a.cpp.elf /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/sketch_sep16a.cpp.eep 
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/sketch_sep16a.cpp.elf /tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/sketch_sep16a.cpp.hex 

Sketch uses 4,252 bytes (14%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28,672 bytes.
Global variables use 151 bytes (5%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2,409 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,560 bytes.
Forcing reset using 1200bps open/close on port /dev/ttyACM0
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM0, /dev/ttyS0, } / {/dev/ttyACM0, /dev/ttyS0, } => {}
PORTS {/dev/ttyACM0, /dev/ttyS0, } / {/dev/ttyACM0, /dev/ttyS0, } => {}
Uploading using selected port: /dev/ttyACM0
/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/tmp/build6488251228617422525.tmp/sketch_sep16a.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Jan 15 2015 at 13:12:29
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/phas/Downloads/arduino-1.7.10-linux64/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/phas/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Comment: Might be an Arduino cc vs org kind of thing in the IDE. Check using the IDE from org.

Comment: I don't think CC make the Leonardo any more (yes, looking at the site it is "retired"). So it must be a .org board. Maybe you have the wrong programmer selected?

Comment: Enable verbose output in the Arduino settings to get a more elaborate error message.

Comment: Personally I'd pick the [chipKIT Lenny](http://majenko.co.uk/lenny) over the Leonardo any day ;)

Comment: @MikaelPatel might it be the opposite?

Comment: Just by looking at the picture, the silkscreen on the board clearly states `ARDUINO.ORG`. 
It is possible you need to download the IDE from arduino.org (they have their own stupid fork).

Comment: Uninstall the modem-manager package in Linux.

Comment: @Majenko did that, didn't work. Same error.

Comment: @RiccardoCagnasso Damn, worth a try. You might like to check through this and see if there is anything else that may help: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/diagnosing-arduino-problems-in-linux/

Comment: @Majenko nope, nothing useful there. I thoght it would be a permissions problem but nope. I will try it on windows to narrow it down.

Comment: I went on windows, i used the arduino.org IDE to flash "Blink" on it and it worked. And them BAM it started working on linux with android.cc IDE.

My knowledge of arduino's internals is limited, but I guess that there was "something" wrong that was overwritten flashing the sketch.

If someone want to elaborate a proper answer from this ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has elaborated a better answer: if something like this happens, try to install arduino.org IDE on windows, connect the leonardo and flash a firmware. It should then start to work on any OS.